# CopyOnWriteArraySet vs ConcurrentHashMap-backed Set

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, concurrency

Suppose you need inter-thread shared unordered `Set` of elements. Options are `CopyOnWriteArraySet` and `ConcurrentHashMap`-backed `Set` created by `Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<E, Boolean>())`. Both are thread-safe, both are safe to iterate and do not throw `ConcurrentModificationException`, but unlike map-backed one, `CopyOnWriteArraySet` has `O(n)` complexity on mutation operations.

So the question is in which cases `CopyOnWriteArraySet` is really better?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In cases where you don't need to mutate the set (at least often).